# Replacing Phone Numbers on Page with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am trying to replace all instances of a particular phone number in an html document with javascript.

The phone numbers may come in multiple forms:

888-888-8888

(888)-888-8888

(888) 888-8888

http://jsfiddle.net/2ARgD/2/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function p(a,b,element){
        if(!element)element=document.body;
        var nodes=$(element).contents().each(function(){
                if(this.nodeType==Node.TEXT_NODE){
                    var r=new RegExp(a,'gi');
                          this.textContent=this.textContent.replace(r,b);
                } else { 
                    p(a,b,this);
                }
        });
    }
    p('888-888-8888','(999)-999-9999');
    p('(888)-888-8888','(999)-999-9999');
    p('(888) 888-8888','(999)-999-9999');
});
```

It successfully replaces all instances of the first form listed about. But Seems to ignore the parentheses. I have tried escaping with a backslash with no luck. My regex skills are not very good so I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: I'd recommend playing with your expressions on http://refiddle.com/, but it's currently down.

Comment: OK. I've never heard of that one, thanks so much!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because you're passing the string on to create a regular expression, you need to escape the parenthesis:

```
p('888-888-8888','(999)-999-9999');
p('\\(888\\)-888-8888','(999)-999-9999');
p('\\(888\\) 888-8888','(999)-999-9999');
```

Another way would be to use a single pattern:

```
p('(888-|\\(888\\)[- ])888-8888','(999)-999-9999');
```

Answer (score 2):

## Description

If you're already sure the value is a phone number then you could use this expression which allows any non-numeric delimiter between any of the sections, or even no delimters at all

Regex: `^\D?(\d{3})\D?\D?(\d{3})\D?(\d{4})`

Replace with: `($1)-$2-$3`

[image]

To match all instances of a particular number you could use this:

`^\D?(888)\D?\D?(888)\D?(8888)` and the same replacement `($1)-$2-$3`.

## Javascript example

**Input Samples**

```
0001112222
188-818-8818
288-828-8828
(388)-838-8838
(488) 848-8848
```

**Code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var re = /^\D?(\d{3})\D?\D?(\d{3})\D?(\d{4})/;
  var sourcestring = "source string to match with pattern";
  var replacementpattern = "($1)-$2-$3";
  var result = sourcestring.replace(re, replacementpattern);
  alert("result = " + result);
</script>
```

**After Replacement**

```
(000)-111-2222
(188)-818-8818
(288)-828-8828
(388)-838-8838
(488)-848-8848
```

Comment: Hey, that's a nice diagram. Is there a tool that made it?

Comment: Hey Grim,  I'm using debuggex.com. Although it doesn't support lookbehinds, named capture groups, or atomic groups it's still handy for understanding the expression flow. There is also regexper.com. They do a pretty good job too, but it's not real time as you're typing.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Regex:

```
$("p").each(function() {
    var rep = $(this).text();
    rep = rep.replace(/\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[- ]([0-9]{3})[- ]([0-9]{4})/, '($1)-$2-$3');
    $(this).text(rep);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hhGgQ/2/

Comment: OP wants to "*replace all instances of a particular phone number*", not all phone numbers. Also, the format of the number that you're replacing it with is incorrect.

Comment: Huh, quite right - I didn't realise it was a particular number. Added some brackets for the output. I figure I'll leave the answer in case someone comes along looking to reformat all the numbers.